# What does this snippet of Javascript do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.post("", {message: msg}, function() {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [jQuery post method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) making a POST request to the current page (I'm guessing here, I'm assuming it just posts to the current page if that parameter is an empty string) with the contents of variable `msg` being passed as a parameter named `message`

Comment: Just wondering... What if I need to pass more than one parameter?

Comment: The second parameter is a JSON object, so you could pass any valid JSON object: {message: msg, id: 1, active: true}

Comment: you would need to know the parameter names and pass it...  example {message: msg, secondParam: parm2, thirdParam: param3}

Comment: @John: it's not JSON, it's a JS object, which is encoded into the request content using either urlencode, or mime-multipart.  no JSON involved.

Comment: You are correct, I misspoke in my haste. Thanks for pointing that out.